# Chain Link oracle : Fail with error 'First word must be requestId'

Tags: blockchain, remix, ether, oracles, chainlink

I just span up an oracle contract using **"@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.7/Operator.sol";**

I am using **Operator.sol** specifically for the **fulfillRequest2** function since i need to return data in the form of bytes instead of bytes32

The request is going through and the oracle is running the job with no errors. However when it wants to return it to my consumer contract, I get this error.

[Link to This Transaction](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0x644acad3c7d7afaa5fce79fc25028674d7e2caa8f56c022b9f3e474b7cdc1fd8)

[image: Error]

The following is my job sepc File my node is running for this job :

```
type = "directrequest"
schemaVersion = 1
name = "Meta Data Processor - Beta"
contractAddress = "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx"
maxTaskDuration = "0s"
observationSource = """
    decode_log   [type="ethabidecodelog"
                  abi="OracleRequest(bytes32 indexed specId, address requester, bytes32 requestId, uint256 payment, address callbackAddr, bytes4 callbackFunctionId, uint256 cancelExpiration, uint256 dataVersion, bytes data)"
                  data="$(jobRun.logData)"
                  topics="$(jobRun.logTopics)"]

    decode_cbor  [type="cborparse" data="$(decode_log.data)"]
    fetch        [type="bridge" name="upload-meta-data" requestData="{\\"data\\":{\\"Class\\": $(decode_cbor.Class),\\"Rarity\\": $(decode_cbor.Rarity), \\"Modifier\\": $(decode_cbor.Modifier),\\"dob\\": $(decode_cbor.dob)}, \\"id\\": $(jobSpec.externalJobID)}"]
    parse        [type="jsonparse" path="url" data="$(fetch)"]
    encode_data  [type="ethabiencode" abi="(bytes value)" data="{ \\"value\\": $(parse) }"]
    encode_tx    [type="ethabiencode"
                  abi="fulfillOracleRequest2(bytes32 requestId, uint256 payment, address callbackAddress, bytes4 callbackFunctionId, uint256 expiration, bytes calldata data)"
                  data="{\\"requestId\\": $(decode_log.requestId), \\"payment\\": $(decode_log.payment), \\"callbackAddress\\": $(decode_log.callbackAddr), \\"callbackFunctionId\\": $(decode_log.callbackFunctionId), \\"expiration\\": $(decode_log.cancelExpiration), \\"data\\": $(encode_data)}"
                 ]
    submit_tx    [type="ethtx" to="xxxx-xxxx-xxxx" data="$(encode_tx)"]

    decode_log -> decode_cbor -> fetch -> parse -> encode_data -> encode_tx -> submit_tx
"""
externalJobID = "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx"
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by changing my encode_data task to this :

```
encode_data  [type="ethabiencode" abi="(bytes32 requestId, bytes value)" data="{\\"requestId\\": $(decode_log.requestId), \\"value\\": $(parse)}"]
```